# Escape unicode (%u2014) in javascript or in C#/.NET?

Tags: javascript, .net, unicode, escaping

I found `%u2014` in the wild west of the internet (actually a review on rotten tomatoes). I remember seeing something like this in javascript. I can't remember if it was in a string or not but I figure its some kind of escape or uri escape.

I tried running `decodeURIComponent('%u2014')` in my console and got `URIError: malformed URI sequence`. Does anyone know how to decode this character? For some reason `\x` comes to mind but i'm not sure why.

How do I decode this unicode character?

Comment: you can try `JSON.parse('"\u2014"')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format `%uNNNN` comes from the JavaScript function `escape()` - it looks a bit like URL-encoding, but it's not, it's a custom (pointless) JS-specific encoding type.

If you're handling it from JavaScript code the obvious antidote is `unescape()`.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can use RegExp for this pattern and do your char decoding from it's matches. Afaik the `%uXXXX` format isn't a recommended practice though.

```
var decodeUE = (function () {
    var reg = /%u([\dA-F]{4})|%([\dA-F]{2})/ig,
        helper = function (m, a, b) {
            if (a) return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16));
            if (b) return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(b, 16));
        };
    return function decodeUE(s) {
        return s.replace(reg, helper);
    };
}());

var enc = '%u2014 %33 %AF %u1A2B';

decodeUE(enc); // "— 3 ¯ ᨫ"
```

Comment: For the reverse, consider `'—'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16); // "2014"`, but you'll have to have some sort of whitelist because we don't encode _every_ character.

Comment: Quick tip. Instead of two if statements you can use `return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a?a:b, 16));`. demo http://jsfiddle.net/S33MS/

Comment: @acidzombie24 You could also do `parseInt(a||b, 16)` there are lots of options ;) I chose for sake of clarity, feel free to make it better! :D

Comment: wth that works? I thought it would return a bool and give me a 1 :|. I tried `a|b` but that does not work

Comment: `a|b` is bitwise => will cast to int (means `x|0` is a neat trick for quick cast if in dec). `||` is logical, `a||b` => if `a` _not_ falsy, return `a`, otherwise return `b`, there is no cast to bool. You can think of `a ? a : b` as the same as `a && a || b` (but only because the `||` will short circuit as LHS of `&&` _true_ implies RHS _true_), which simplifies to `a || b`. _JavaScript_ is crazy like that.

Comment: I was a bit worried with doing a|b but realized one side must be false and would likely be converted to 0 if it were to do a bitwise or. However... I do too much C++ I just THOUGHT it would NEVER return the original value. Only true and false (like C#) or 1/0 like C++. Well... at least we both agree a?a:b is clear? Maybe || is more clear if the reader understands it